# VLC media player cannot open video in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04

I have Ubuntu 12.04 , I tried downloading the appropriate media player (VLC), but I still can't watch any video content.

Comment: can you open vlc? what kind of error do you have, provide us with more info and/or screenshots so we can gelp you

Comment: Have you installed Ubuntu Restricted Extras?

Answer (score 0):

The most reason would be to install Ubuntu extras.  To do so, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing whatever you installed first:

```
sudo apt-get remove packageinstalled
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Then install this way:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc browser-plugin-vlc
```

This is what their site recommends: http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-ubuntu.html. I recently installed it and can play .mp4 files on a fresh 12.04 install.